How to update commons-text-1.9.jar with commons-text-1.10.0 in SpringSource Tool Suite (STS4) server implementation?
Apache commons-text-1.9.jar has a vulnerability.   If I find the file and replace it with commons-text-1.10.1.jar the web server won't start inside Eclipse.  How can I do this?
It's been so long since I ran the "Check for Updates" and tried to update the list, it fails.  There are repositories that can't be found.
What is the way to update the STS4 installation to reference an updated version of commons-text?  I'm using the tomcat v9.0.
Path to file:
C:\STS4\sts- 4.16.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls_1.40.0.202210240737\servers\spring-boot-language-server\BOOT-INF\lib\commons-text-1.9.jar

Thx.

I would recommend to download a fresh copy of the latest release from https://spring.io/tools and go from there.
But I think this is completely unrelated to the way you start Tomcat from within your IDE, that sounds like a different problem. And I don't see why replacing the JAR file inside of the language server directly affects the Tomcat integration in the IDE, those a two completely different areas.

Can I reinstall STS right into the same folder and not have it mess up anything I currently have in the workspace?  after backing it up of course.

The installation folder of the Spring Tools for Eclipse is separate from the workspace folder that you opened in the IDE and imported your projects into. I would recommend to use a fresh and empty folder to install the IDE into, but you can - of course - open the existing workspace with all your projects and settings.

One more comment: Once you opened your workspace with a newer version of the IDE, it might not be easy to go back to an older version of the IDE and re-use the same workspace. There is only forward-migration in place, not backward-migration (of existing workspaces). So a backup of the workspace folder is a good idea.

My problem was that I renamed the offending jar commmons-text-1.9.jar and left it in the folder rather than deleting it when I added commons-text-1.10.1.jar.  I was seeing version conflicts.
My bad.  I should have known better.
